# If $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ and $\chi_Af_n,\chi_Af \in L^1$ does $\chi_Af_n \to \chi_Af$ in $L^1$?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

This question came up when trying to prove a weaker statement that: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int f_n=\int f$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int \chi_Af_n=\int \chi_Af$.

Which I think I can proven using Fatous Lemma. Is the statement in the title true? What would be the proof?

Comment: This function $\chi_{A}$ is the indicator function? If it is, your affirmation follows as a direct application of the definition of converge in $L^{1}$.

Comment: @ABP How so? By definition $\int |f_n-f| \to 0$ not $\int_{A}|f_n-f|\to 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that $f_{n} \to f$ in $L^{1}(X)$ and $A \subset X$, then 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{A}{|f_{n}(x) - f(x)|}dx &=& \int_{X}{|\chi_{A}(x)||f_{n}(x) - f(x)|} dx \\
& \leq & \int_{X}{|f_{n}(x) - f(x)|}dx \to 0.
\end{eqnarray}